# why oracle shows only 9999 max value for VARCHAR datatype?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one table where I had set column type as `VARCHAR` with `9 BYTE`, but when applying max function on this column, it shows only max value as 9999 and no more than that,

```
create table test(
ID  NUMBER,
NAME    VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
SAL NUMBER,
RANK    VARCHAR2(9 BYTE));

Insert into test (ID,NAME,SAL,RANK  ) values (1082,'ABC',2082,'9999');
Insert into test (ID,NAME,SAL,RANK  ) values (1083,'ABC',2083,'10000');
```

Actual data:

```
id      NAME      SAL    RANK   
1082    ABC      2082   9999
1083    ABC      2083   10000
```

Query

```
select * from test where RANK   =(select max(RANK   ) from testyy);
```

output:

```
id      NAME      SAL    RANK   
1082    ABC   2082       9999
```

I had tried to make column empty and modify column to INTEGER, then it works, but I am in question why it does not works for  9 BYTE data type

```
update test set RANK    =null where id=1082;
update test set RANK    =null where id=1083;
alter table test modify RANK    INTEGER;

update test set RANK    ='9999' where id=1082;
update test set RANK    ='10000' where id=1083;

select * from test where RANK   =(select max(RANK) from test);

id      NAME      SAL    RANK   
------------------------------------------
1083    ABC      2083   10000
```

There is no error message from Oracle SQL developer

Comment: Store numbers as numbers, not as text. Because `"9"` is greater than `"1000000000000000000000"` in dictionary order.

Comment: **Never** store numbers in a `varchar` column - and this question is a very good example on why you should not do it.

Comment: You might want to read about [character value comparison](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Data-Type-Comparison-Rules.html#GUID-A114F1F4-A08D-4107-B679-323DC7FEA31C) and related (by default) [binary value comparison](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Data-Type-Comparison-Rules.html#GUID-0F560FC8-3ADF-4AFD-87BA-E4673EFEE9FA).

Comment: The simple answer is that there is no `9 BYTE` data type. The data type you have is `VARCHAR`, meaning "string". 9 BYTE is only a limit on the size (length) of strings allowed in the column. 9 BYTE means at most nine bytes; bytes, not characters, which means that if your character set is multi-byte (for example for Chinese text) you have room for less than 9 characters. All your characters are digits, so in that case "9 bytes" is the same as "9 characters". Nothing else to do with "bytes", and again, the data type is a form of "string".

Comment: Which is greater, '9' or '1'?

Comment: It's due to text value, I understood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting this answer to correct a fundamental misunderstanding you have with regards to your table setup

You're asserting that this statement creates a column with a byte datatype:

```
CREATE TABLE X( Y VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) )
```

Absolutely nothing to do with Bytes in the commonly understood programming notion of "a byte is 8 bits and stores a number between 0 and 255 (or 0x00 and 0xFF)

The datatype of this column is VARCHAR2, i.e. text. Not bytes. Not numbers. Not numeric

The presence of BYTE instructs oracle to use at most 100 bytes of storage space to contain the text. This means if you insert Unicode characters that require 4 bytes per character you'll only be able to get 25 chars in there before oracle tells you your string is too long. If you insert ascii characters, which require 1 byte per char, you'll get 100 characters in there before oracle tells you your string is too long

The complement of BYTE here is CHAR where you tell oracle "use as much space on disk as you need so long as you accept strings up to 100 chars long". That means oracle will use between 100 and 400 bytes of space on disk to store your characters

-

The other answers have covered why a string of '9999' is "greater than" a string of '10000' but i do have a nugget to add on why it's so:

'9' as a character is at position 0x39 in the ascii table and numerically thus is "worth" 57 (base 10 representation of 0x39 hex)

'1' as a character is at position 0x31 in the ascii table and numerically thus is "worth" 49 (base 10 representation of 0x31 hex)

When oracle is comparing strings (in a left to right language) and asking "which string is alphabetically after/greater the other?" it works from left to right comparing character by character

In his case it does the first character:

```
Is '9' greater than '1'? 
--> What are the numeric representations of these characters? 57 and 49
--> Is 57 greater than 49? 
--> Yes. '9' is greater than '1'. 
--> STOP and declare '9999' is bigger than '10000'
```

It stops because there are no more comparisons needed. If both strings started with '9' they would tie on comparing the first character and oracle would move on to comparing the second character in order to decide which one was the winner.. and so on

So there you have it: 9999 is nothing to do with '9999' - one is a number and one is text that looks like a number. This question is nothing to do with numeric based comparison, Max values of a byte etc

It's purely about how strings/text is sorted, and that's what you need to get down with

Never store numbers that you want to work with mathematically, in a varchar; they take up more space, are slower, and give rise to errors in sorting, math and require conversion every time they're used

Comment: Dear Caius Jard, thanks for lesson and satisfactory answer

Answer (score 6):

Because `rank` is varchar in your table and in this case `9999` is greater than `10000`, so `9999` is max.

Comment: It's all quantum, I suspect... :-)

Answer (score 3):

When you order by a string, you use lexicographic order, where 100 comes before 99 (the same way as 'a' comes before bb'), while when you order by a number, you consider its value, so 100 > 90.

For example:

```
SQL> create table testOrder (num number, str varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> insert into testOrder values (99, '99');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into testOrder values (100, '100');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from testOrder order by num;

       NUM STR
---------- ----------
        99 99
       100 100

SQL> select * from testOrder order by str;

       NUM STR
---------- ----------
       100 100
        99 99
```

Comment: You mean that if numeric value exist in string variable then strings are sorted based on their ASCII sequence comparing each character order from left to right, thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you use `VARCHAR` as your datatype the `MAX` function will behave as if the data is text.

When ordering text "ZEBRA" is after "ALIGATOR" even if "ALIGATOR" has more letters. Applying the same logic to "9999" and "10000" then "9999" is the greater of the two as the first VARCHAR "9" of "9999" is after the first VARCHAR "1" of "10000".